# how do i make the frame display none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook, facebook-iframe

I have this invite facebook iframe that i am using on my site

```
 <fb:serverfbml width="565px" class=" fb_iframe_widget">
```

but i need to display none and click a button and display it ...i assumed that i could do

```
 .fb_iframe_widget  display:none;

 }
```

but for some reason regardless of what i put the display none on it always displays...hope can i hide the frame with jquery, javascript, or css ....any help thanks

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping that in div that you have full control over it, that way you can hide it and make it visible when your button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

your css does not seem right maybe that might be the problem.
try this.

`.fb_iframe_widget {display:none;}`